# Deploy React components to many personal projects

Tags: reactjs, meteor, npm

I hope this is a reasonable forum for this question.

I have a library of React components that I've developed that I'd like to use in multiple personal projects. When I update/improve that library I'd like it to allow me to update in all projects where it is used.

I'm using Meteor as a build tool, which will prompt me when there is an update available for a dependency it's using, so I assume it'd be an NPM module or something. It is checked in to GitHub and I don't mind if it's public.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I know two ways:

1. Publish your module on NPM
2. Link using `npm link`

For the first one, your module will be public unless you pay NPM for a private module.

The second one, make your module available locally only (It is used for a development purpose, but it fits your needs).

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Answer (score 2):

If you have your package published on GitHub, you can simply create dependency by linking to `tarball/master`. If your path is `https://github.com/my-nick/my-package`, just add to your dependencies in your project's `package.json`:

```
"my-package": "https://github.com/my-nick/my-package/tarball/master"
```

If you have your package well described (`package.json` file with `name`, `main` and `version` attributes) it should works after `meteor npm install`.

Of course it works for Meteor 1.3 and higher only, lower versions don't support npm.

Answer (score 1):

I did not use is personally yet, but an frequently mentioned tool for this purpose is https://lernajs.io/, which is e.g. used by create-react-app.